# Javascript/PHP - find if the client is in the same network

Tags: javascript, php, lan

I have an website hosted on local server in my LAN network. This server is exposed outside by port forwarding from router. I want to know if a client connects from outside the LAN or inside the LAN

Comment: IP check.... if someone is to access the website within your network that person will share the same IP as the server IP, any other IP's connected will be connections from outside of your local network.

Comment: You could check the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in PHP. You should already know the IP of your server, if `REMOTE_ADDR` is in the same subnetwork (or generally if it is a private IP address), then the client is local.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any request to your server that has been port forwarded will appear to originate from the IP address of the device that performed the port forwarding.

So you just need to test:

```
if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == $the_ip_address_of_the_router_on_the_lan)
```

where `$the_ip_address_of_the_router_on_the_lan` is a known value such as `192.168.0.1`.

Devices on the LAN, assuming they access your server directly, will make requests that appear to originate from their own LAN IP address.

*Warning*: If the server is accessed using a hostname (such as `foo.example.com`), and you use the same hostname both inside and outside the LAN, and the DNS inside the LAN points that hostname to the Internet facing ip address of the router, then the requests will still be port forwarded by the router.

Comment: I use dns hostname but in the LAN i have add a static DNS entry in my router with points directly to the server local adres. So i think it should be not forwarded by the router?